# Laravel 7 Download File from AWS S3 with Laravel Storage and delete it after

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, storage

Before using the s3 driver, I did it like this

```
return response()->download(storage_path($path_to_file), $filename)->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
```

But now I don't know how to delete the file after downloading

```
return Storage::disk('s3')->get($path_to_file);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$file = Storage::disk('s3')->get($path_to_file);
Storage::disk('s3')->delete($path_to_file);

return $file;
```

Not sure if its possible to chain a delete, could give it a go.

Answer (score 2):

You might download the file then delete it!

```
//download the file 
Storage::disk('s3')->get($file);
// delete it I prefer to make job for that 
Storage::disk('s3')->delete($file);
```